# Django: Is there any performance differences when using ajax?

Tags: django

I'm working on refactoring project in the middle of the work. There are a lot of context when view return render. I want to change it to get response when dom rendered using ajax.

I know it makes more request, but I wondered if there are any performance differences. If not, I want to do that.

Comment: from my experience, you only use AJAX when you want to interact with data on the same page without reloading the entire page. Django context is used to provide initial datas when the page first load

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding, using AJAX and context are completely different methods.

AJAX does things on the client-side, while the Django context works on the server.

According to this basic difference, and considering the size of your page is large and multiple time changes, the AJAX is faster because you will only be requesting the data and not the whole page

But

If we assume the size of your page is large but data don't change frequently, the Django-Context is better in the scope of security and usability, because you will not expose the data that is to be rendered as it will be if used AJAX.

So it depends on your use case, if it's a static page then it is better to use django-context than AJAX and if it's a dynamic page use AJAX.

Comment: Thanks. So, you mean if it's a static page then django-context is better even if context is too long?